# Inserting a column in the end in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

My dataset looks like this

[image]

Category    dummy1  dummy2

Aan
Abd
Bad
Boy
Abcd

I want to insert a column names "RESULT" in the end, with conditions
if category starts with a then RESULT="PASS"
if category starts with b then RESULT="FAIL"

ie, my final output should be like this

[image]

How can I do this in excel-vba. Please help me.

I am editing the existing spreadsheets.

```
Dim rngTemp As Range
Set rngTemp = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

For Each cel In Range(Cells(1, 1), rngTemp)
If cel.Value = "I currently live in" Then
cel.Value = "Current_Domicile"
ElseIf cel.Value = "I am interested in purchasing" Then
cel.Value = "Type_of_Property"
ElseIf cel.Value = "I am interested in purchasing" Then
cel.Value = "Wait_Time"
ElseIf cel.Value = "The reason that I am not buying a house right away is because I am:" Then
cel.Value = "Reason_for_Wait"
End If
Next Cel
```

I want to add a new column with the conditions above.

Comment: Why vba? This is easily done with a formula. Show what code you have and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Actually, I am dealing with 10 similar files. Most of the work are done in Excel-VBA till now.

Comment: Again, show the code you have so far. Show where you are stuck. Edit your post and add the code.

Comment: I am editing the existing spreadsheets. I want to add a new column with the condition similar to  if category starts with 'A' then RESULT="PASS" if category starts with 'B' then RESULT="FAIL".

Comment: What if it doesn't start with either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the "files" you mentioned were workbooks or worksheets?
Anyway,I try with the following code and it worked fine. Hope it help in solving your problem.

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MyWorksheet As Worksheet

Sub AddLastColumn()
Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set MyWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("WorksheetName")

Dim MyWorksheetLastRow As Long
Dim MyWorksheetLastColumn As Long
Dim MyRowPointer As Long

MyWorksheetLastColumn = MyWorksheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
MyWorksheet.Cells(1, MyWorksheetLastColumn + 1).Value = "Result"

MyWorksheetLastRow = MyWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For MyRowPointer = 2 To MyWorksheetLastRow

If InStr(1, MyWorksheet.Cells(MyRowPointer, 1), "A") = 1 Then
    MyWorksheet.Cells(MyRowPointer, MyWorksheetLastColumn + 1).Value = "PASS"
Else
    MyWorksheet.Cells(MyRowPointer, MyWorksheetLastColumn + 1).Value = "FAIL"
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Whilst this is well structured code (except the for next indent) here are the reasons I think it is not the correct answer: (1) Try and run this on a dataset with more than 255 rows, Dimming as a Byte restricts this, they should be Longs. (2) This uses a loop when one is not needed (Take a look at my answer for how to avoid this), Loops take time. (3) Too many variable when they are not needed ie MyWorksheetLastRow is used once so why put it in a variable? (4) No need to complicate things with InStr when Left will suffice. Why not just use If Left(MyWorksheet.Cells(MyRowPointer, 1),1)="A" then

Comment: Assigning values in a cell-by-cell manner is slow. Creating an array of array of one variant and then assigning it to the value of the target range will speed up the process significantly. Instead of `MyWorksheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`the `UsedRange` property of the `Worksheet` sould be used.

Comment: Do not `Dim` last rows as Byte. There is absolutely no reason to do that and as Dan Danoghue mentioned might lead to errors.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use for loop to read the code like this

```
Sub main()


Dim i, n As Integer
Range("A1").Select

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    n = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A2").Select

For i = 2 To n

Currentcell = Cells(i, 1).Value

If Left(Currentcell, 1) = "a" Then

Cells(i, 4).Value = "true"


ElseIf Left(Currentcell, 1) = "b" Then

Cells(i, 4).Value = "false"



Else

End If

Next i
End Sub
```

First take the value of the cell where you want to start and store it in a string, then check whether it is starting with a or b. Then store the value you required in the required cell and continue this till you find the empty cell. Because of that reason i took an integer which counts the range using exceldown.

Iam sorry there was some bug, you can now try like this it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much.
But when I tried, it didn't work. Also, how to add the column name for the new column we created?

Comment: firs activate worksheet and then try the code, i wrote it here , just check if there are any bugs in the code. The format is correct i didnt wrote in vba. To give the value just write this Range(your destination cell).value = "your title name"

Comment: if you are creating a new column, use .End(xlToRight) and write in the last column

Comment: Yes. I am creating a new column. The problem with naming that column using "Range(your destination cell).value = "your title name" " is I don't know my destination cell's address in prior. Because some files have 10 columns, others have 13,14 etc columns. I want to insert a column in the end and Give it a specified name.

Comment: Hey select the top cell of header part and use xltoright and find the empty column and then give a value to it

Comment: Don't use XLDown or XLRight, it will give false results when it encounters blanks, always come from the bottom up or from the right to the left eg: Range("A" & Rows.count).end(xlup).row will give you the REAL last row, Range("A1").end(xldown).row gives you the first blank

Answer (score 1):

I would go without the loop and take advantage of Excel's inbuilt IF formula:

```
Sub StartsWithA()
    Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 1).Resize(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1, 1) = "=IF(UPPER(LEFT(A2,1))=""A"",""pass"",""fail"")"
    Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Formula = "Result"
    activesheet.calculate 'In case your calcs are set to manual
    Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 0).Resize(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 1).Copy
    Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 0).Resize(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```